# SQL Server Job creating large output file

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that I want to run as a job, but it creates a VERY LARGE output file.  I can run the query in SQL Studio and it runs pretty fast, I then direct the output to a file.  It creates the file at around 2 meg.  I then create it as a job and select to create a new output file each time.  The job takes longer to run and the output comes out as 1.2 gigs in size. There is a lot of white space in the output file. Am I missing something in creating this job and output?

Comment: Show the query, do you run it on different servers (DEV/PROD)?

Comment: query is too long to post here.  Only get 600 characters.  Not sure what the query would show though.  It is running in SQL Studio query tool just fine, but when I create it as a job and run it, it comes out with that large file.  It is running the same query on the same database.

Comment: @John "below is the query" - where ??

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), the output column length can be set in Tools | Options... | Query Results > SQL Server > Results to Text.  I think the default is 256.  Your SSMS results may be limited by this setting.

Comment: what would setting the output column length do to make the file larger/smaller?

Comment: You mentioned it has a lot of white space (that is our only clue so far). Maybe it just takes that much space? If you run it in SSMS then copy paste into a text file how much space does it use? If it is a lot smaller... **you need to inspect it and give us a more specific clue**

Comment: I run it in SSMS and select to save to file instead of grid, and the file is 2M in size.  I paste the same code into a scheduled job and then the file comes out as 1.2 gigs.

Comment: By "save to file" in your job you are mean within the T-SQL Script step, on the Advanced tab, you choose "Output File", no?  First, confirm the "Append output to existing file" is not checked (which would explain your growth).  Second, note that the SQL Agent T-SQL output files are in encoded as "UCS-2 LE BOM", so essentially UTF-16.  The default SSMS "Results to file" encoding is "UTF-8 BOM", which will be significantly smaller than the job encoding.  Also assume you aren't clicking the "Save with Encoding..." option and saving as "ANSI", which also be smaller than the default SSMS output.

Comment: Yes, I am using T-SQL and clicking on Output File on the advanced tab, and Append to file is unchecked.  Is there a way to change the UTF-16?

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008 and don't see Save With Encoding or save as ANSI.

Comment: @John I have not found any way to change the output file encoding for SQL agent steps.  The only workaround I know of is to instead run the TSQL script as an Operating System command, calling sqlcmd input and output parameter.  You can then have some control over the encoding.